# Client-server storage with persistent, renameable files, renaming history

Tags: file-management, version-control, archiving

Users should be allowed to...

- upload files
- rename files after upload
- view the renaming history of a file.

User should NOT be allowed to...

- delete any file
- change the contents of any file
- manipulate the renaming history of any file.

Additionally, it would be nice if with a special admin-type access mode, deletion of files would still be possible. But this is not so important.

Web-based access would be good; also it should be possible for users to mirror the file tree on their local file systems and keep it in sync there with what happens on the server.

Server should run on Linux.

Many revision control systems can be used for this task, but lead to a duplication of data upon checkout (factor 2). This holds in particular for Mercurial, even with the Largefiles extension.

I tested Owncloud, but did not see how to protect against deletion and how to see renaming history.

Comment: What is your budget? I would recommend Alfresco Records Management (which I have installed and tried), but I am not sure whether it allows file renaming or not.